# web_reg_save_param_regexp not extracting data

Tags: regex, loadrunner

I've just started working with Loadrunner and I wanted to extract some data from a response.I used the  web_reg_save_param_regexp() function to extract some data but would get the error -

Error -35049: No match found for the requested parameter "UserDetails". Check whether the requested regular expression exists in the response data     [MsgId: MERR-35049]

This is just the part of the response data that i need to be extracted.

**{"name":"Alice Duval","id":"59"},{"name":"Amadi Aswad","id":"73"},{"name":"Andrew Daley","id":"50"},{"name":"Andrew Keller","id":"89"},**

The regular expression I'm using is,
**{\"name\":\"(\w+\s+\w+)\"\,\"id\":\"(\d+)\"}**
This expression works,I think its the usage thats causing the problem.

```
web_reg_save_param_regexp("ParamName=UserDetails",

"RegExp=\{\"name\"\:\"(\w+\s+\w+)\"\,\"id\"\:\"(\d+)\"\}",
SEARCH_FILTERS,
"Scope=Body",
"RequestUrl=*/onboarding/viewTaskTypes*",
"GROUP=1",
 LAST);
 web_url("viewTaskTypes",       "URL=http://peguser.trials621.orangehrmlive.com/onboarding/viewTaskTypes", 
        "Resource=0", 
        "RecContentType=text/html",         "Referer=http://peguser.trials621.orangehrmlive.com/onboarding/viewTaskTypes", 
        "Snapshot=t176.inf", 
        "Mode=HTTP", 
        LAST);
```

Comment: Are you sure all those backslashes are needed? I think only " need the backslash so that it won't be confused with the end of string. http://regexr.com/3g3qr

Comment: @Buzzy I had used \ only for the double quotes and the braces initially.That didnt work. I was getting syntax errors while compiling.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out. You need double backslash where there is a slash in the RegExp and no slash where there is no special character:

```
"RegExp={\"name\":\"(\\w+\\s+\\w+)\",\"id\":\"(\\d+)\"}",
```

Comment: Thanks! It worked.Any idea how to use both the capturing groups. I tried using UserDetails1 and UserDetails2 to use values in the capturing groups.However it didnt work and I was only able to use UserDetails1.

Comment: I think you need to have two calls to web_reg_save_param_regexp, one for each part (i.e. name and id). Then change the Group=

Comment: Also, if the server response is JSON there is web_reg_save_param_json which should be even easier to use

Comment: response is HTML.In JMeter,it is possible to use the values from the multiple capturing groups by just using it as var_g1,var_g2.
According to this [blog](http://www.jds.net.au/correlation-with-regex/)
it must be possible,I used their approach,but it didnt work.
I want to use both values from the single regex without any calls.

Comment: I asked our scripting expert and he said it was impossible. He said to use two calls to web_reg_save_param_regexp and store each group to a different param. I think using Ordianl=All will just give you all the matches of that group but not all the groups.